# Why docker container always be killed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run docker container to start a springboot restful api:

```
docker run api:latest
```

Then it exits with error code 137, and printed a "Killed" at the end:

```
2018-05-19 13:36:08.571  INFO 8 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-05-19 13:36:08.581  INFO 8 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2018-05-19 13:36:08.737  INFO 8 --- [           main] b.c.e.u.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainer : Undertow started on port(s) 8080 (http)
2018-05-19 13:36:08.751  INFO 8 --- [           main] org.smarter.Application                  : Started Application in 8.63 seconds (JVM running for 9.454)
Killed
```

I didn't specify any resource limit to it, why it's exited with error code 137?

Answer (score 1):

If your Docker image is running a JDK8u131+ or JDK9+, check "[Running a JVM in a Container Without Getting Killed](https://blog.csanchez.org/2017/05/31/running-a-jvm-in-a-container-without-getting-killed/)" from **[Carlos Sanchez](https://twitter.com/csanchez)**.
A JDK would default in most cases to a max heap of 1/4 of the *host* memory, not the container.

Try, as in this [spring-boot-web-docker `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/dragankoz/spring-boot-web-docker/blob/master/app/src/main/docker/Dockerfile), to add

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=1 -XshowSettings:vm"
```

(building your own custom image on top of the one you are trying to use)

Those options come from "[Java SE support for Docker CPU and memory limits](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/java-se-support-for-docker-cpu-and-memory-limits)" (May 2017).